# Radio Buttons and

Tags: html, laravel, radio-button

I'm creating a form for a page with my Laravel app and I want to know if anyone can tell me how I can fix this so that when my form loads up there isn't any options preselected because for some reason when I go to create a new entity on the create form there’s already selection made.

```
<div class="radio-custom radio-primary radio-inline">
    <input id="active" type="radio" name="is_active" {{ (old('is_active') == NULL || ((isset($title) && $title->is_active == 1)))  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="1">
    <label for="active">Active</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-custom radio-primary radio-inline">
    <input id="active" type="radio" name="is_active" {{ (old('is_active') == NULL || ((isset($title) && $title->is_active == 0)))  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="0">
    <label for="inactive">Inactive</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to uncheck your boxes?
On every page (edit+create forms) or just on the creation page?

Comment: Well I just want to make sure there is no pre-selected radio button when the create field is loaded. As of right now when the create form is loaded the inactive radio button is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. You have an logical error within your if/else statement. Whenever there is no old value you try to check both radio buttons.

```
<div class="radio-custom radio-primary radio-inline">
    <input id="active" type="radio" name="is_active" {{ (old('is_active') !== NULL || ((isset($title) && $title->is_active == 1)))  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="1">
    <label for="active">Active</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-custom radio-primary radio-inline">
    <input id="active" type="radio" name="is_active" {{ (old('is_active') !== NULL || ((isset($title) && $title->is_active == 0)))  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="0">
    <label for="inactive">Inactive</label>
</div>
```

This should work as well:

```
<div class="radio-custom radio-primary radio-inline">
    <input id="active" type="radio" name="is_active" {{ (isset($title) && $title->is_active == 1)  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="1">
    <label for="active">Active</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-custom radio-primary radio-inline">
    <input id="active" type="radio" name="is_active" {{  (isset($title) && $title->is_active == 0)  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="0">
    <label for="inactive">Inactive</label>
</div>
```

Hope this solved your problem. :) 
Highly prefer the second solution since the first one is just unnecessary code.

Comment: I think you have an issue with that second solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with the values being cached in your browser. Try adding `autocomplete='off'` in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: I made an attempt at that possible solution and received the same results.

Comment: also you shouldn't use the same ID for 2 different elements in HTML

Comment: I guess the problem has to do something with `old('is_active') == NULL`. You are checking for the same thing in both radio inputs and it being true will cause both radios to be selected which is impossible